# How to get smooth animation of my custom annotation on mapView ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mapkit

In my app I am showing user annotation(custom annotation with user thumbnail) on map. Whenever User changes location or user moves I also change my annotation position according to user location but right now it has blinking effect as I add and remove annotation on map. I want smooth animation of my annotation whenever user moves. How can I achieve that.

I have to remove and add annotation everytime. but removing and adding annotations is not a good approach it creates blinking effect when user is moving or driving.

Plzz can anyone help with this issue.

Comment: may i know what is the importance of custom annotation here?, for adding an image you are using that?

Comment: yeah, for adding image and to show some more info on annotation Info view(callout view). like address, time and name

Comment: is this solved ? I am trying to acheive nearly same.

Answer (score 1):

Are you replacing the default `MKUserLocation` or are you manually tracking in Core Location and adding your own annotation? You should be able to do this smoothly by just returning a customer user location annotation in your delegate.